# Multiple tracking-mode elements within a single session-config element in the web.xml?

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I am using Tomcat 8.0.35 for my web application. This post

https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/java-servlet/session-tracking-mode.html

says that we can use multiple tracking-mode elements within a single session-config element in the web.xml

```
<web-app>
    <session-config>
        <tracking-mode>???</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
 </web-app>
```

I am not able to find the additional information about "multiple tracking-mode elements". What could be Tomcat's behavior if I have the following?

```
<web-app>
    <session-config>
        <tracking-mode>URL</tracking-mode>
        <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
    </session-config>
 </web-app>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question can be found in `org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter#postParseRequest`

The following code is from tomcat 8.5:

```
            String sessionID;
            if (request.getServletContext().getEffectiveSessionTrackingModes()
                    .contains(SessionTrackingMode.URL)) {

                // Get the session ID if there was one
                sessionID = request.getPathParameter(
                        SessionConfig.getSessionUriParamName(
                                request.getContext()));
                if (sessionID != null) {
                    request.setRequestedSessionId(sessionID);
                    request.setRequestedSessionURL(true);
                }
            }

            // Look for session ID in cookies and SSL session
            parseSessionCookiesId(request);
            parseSessionSslId(request);

            sessionID = request.getRequestedSessionId();
```

The following happens:

1. If tomcat is allowed to use URL session trcking it tries to find a sessionId in the URL request
2. If it's allowed to use cookie tracking - it looks for session id in the cookies. It takes precedence, regardless if there was a session id in the request or not.
3. (Not part of your question, but for completeness) SSL Session tracking is used if and only if it's the only allowed tracking mode. Otherwise it will be ignored.

I do not know why the URL tracking was not extracted in a sepratate method like for the SSL and Cookie tracking modes, but they look almost identical:

1. Check if the mode is enabled
2. Try to find SessionId
3. Set the Session ID in the Request object.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat 7's `tracking-mode` feature replaced [tomcat 6's disableURLRewriting](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html)

> Context.disableURLRewriting: This has been removed. An equivalent effect can be obtained by configuring the session-config/tracking-mode elements in a web application or in the global CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml file.

You can [Disable JSESSIONID in URL](https://fralef.me/tomcat-disable-jsessionid-in-url.html)

> Servlet 3.0 standard gives you two ways to disable URL session rewriting. This works in Tomcat 7, Glassfish v3, and any other Servlet 3.0-compliant servlet container

Comment: tracking mode is part of the servlet specification, hence it is valid for all servlet containers, including tomcat 8

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I removed the quote